# How to make my secondary navigation menu responsive for mobile devices in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive

I am using newspaper `wordpress` theme and inside this theme i created a custom menu just under my main navigation menu and it works fine, but now i want this secondary menu to be responsive on mobile devices.
I want this menu to simple slide down when someone click on caret icon.
this is the css class i am using to style this menu.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 div.custom-menu-class ul{
 list-style: none;
 float: right;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #b9f6ca;
 padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
 margin-top: -3px; 
 }
div.custom-menu-class ul li {
 list-style: none;
 float: right;
 position: relative;
  padding-left: 1.3px;
  width: 100%;
 }

}
```

Comment: Does the theme already have a responsive menu? You should probably re-use that code. Or better yet, put your secondary menu links inside the existing responsive menu, perhaps styled differently (e.g. a different background color). You should avoid multiple drop-down menus; that seems like a potentially confusing experience for the user.

Comment: yes the theme already have a responsive menu but i don't want to show secondary menu inside of main menu, in fact i want to show just underneath it with a caret icon so when gets click then it should show all the menu items. cause this is the requirement of the client so i have to provide with this plz help me to achieve this. thanks

Comment: Well you're talking about a basic research task; do you need to know how to research? Go to Google and search "wordpress responsive menu" and you'll get tutorials and plugins. It would be more efficient to re-use whatever javascript the theme is using to pull off its responsive menu, but you could just do another javascript for your own menu too. Another option is to do a CSS-only responsive drop-down, like what this article talks about: https://tutorialzine.com/2015/08/quick-tip-css-only-dropdowns-with-the-checkbox-hack

Comment: @MarsAndBack can you plz explain how can i re use theme exsisting code to show my secondary navigation menu inside theme's primary responsive menu.
i am using newspaper wordpress theme.
i will also provide any additional code if needed
plz help me to figure this out.